# alterar listview play no audio

Tags: listview, onclick, áudio

### Gostaria de mudar esse esquema de listview

ao inves de aperter nos botoes play, quero somente apertar no item da lista e ele (no caso) reproduzir o som e quando eu clicar em outro item ele parar o q estava executando e reproduzir o outro, mas estou com algumas dificuldades, resumidamente Gostaria de so clicar no item e ele ja começar a tocar.

se alguem souber algum tutorial tbm sera muito útil obrigado.

### CustomMusicAdapter.java

```
public class CustomMusicAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<Music> arrayList;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private Boolean flag = true;

public CustomMusicAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Music> arrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName, txtSinger;
    ImageView ivPlay, ivStop;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);
        viewHolder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        viewHolder.txtSinger = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSinger);
        viewHolder.ivPlay = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivPlay);
        viewHolder.ivStop = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivStop);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Music music = arrayList.get(position);

    viewHolder.txtName.setText(music.getName());
    viewHolder.txtSinger.setText(music.getSinger());

    // play music
    viewHolder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(flag){
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, music.getSong());
                flag = false;
            }
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            }
        }
    });

    // stop
    viewHolder.ivStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!flag) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                flag = true;
            }
            viewHolder.ivPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

### Music.java

```
public class Music {
private String name;
private String singer;
private int song;

public Music(String name, String singer, int song) {
    this.name = name;
    this.singer = singer;
    this.song = song;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getSinger() {
    return singer;
}

public void setSinger(String singer) {
    this.singer = singer;
}

public int getSong() {
    return song;
}

public void setSong(int song) {
    this.song = song;
}
}
```

### CustomMusicAdapter.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<Music> arrayList;
private CustomMusicAdapter adapter;
private ListView songList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    songList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.songList);
    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add(new Music("Cảm giác yêu", "Don Nguyễn", R.raw.a));
    arrayList.add(new Music("Cầu vòng tình yêu", "Ustylez", R.raw.b));
    arrayList.add(new Music("Lời anh chưa thể nói", "Hàn Khởi", R.raw.c));
    arrayList.add(new Music("Tan", "Lương Minh Trang", R.raw.d));

    adapter = new CustomMusicAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_music_item, arrayList);
    songList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

[image: print da parte foco que estou com problemas.]

[image: Como esta o app, gostaria sem precisar usar os botoes de play, so clicando no item da executa.]

Como esta o app, gostaria sem precisar usar os botoes de play, so clicando no item da executa.

-Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de `getView` em `CustomMusicAdapter.java` insira o seguinte código abaixo para dar ação ao *click* do item. Veja:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       // aqui dentro você coloca a condição para iniciar
       // e finalizar o áudio. Por exemplo para iniciar, basta
       // usar o código abaixo

       MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, music.getSong());
       mediaPlayer.start();           

    }
});
```

Comment: `viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(flag){
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, music.getSong());
flag = false;
 } else {
mediaPlayer.start();
}`



Parou de funcionar quando uso isso

Comment: @Welyson não entendi. Você ficou com alguma dúvida?

Comment: nem eu eu so quero que quando eu clicar reproduza o audio, mas n consigo ja procurei todo tipo de tutorial no yt mas nenhum especificamente. oq eu quero fazer

Comment: @Welyson editei a resposta para reproduzir o audio.

Comment: não da o app para de funcionar, esse é o link do projeto

(https://github.com/quocnguyenvan/media-player-demo)

Comment: @Welyson você possui os arquivos de áudio dentro do raw no seu projeto? Qual erro que aparece no seu logcat?

Comment: **consegui, muito muito obrigado funcionou**
porem o esquema do projeto ta pra reproduzir quando clica no botao play de cada item como na print do app, mas eu gostaria de reproduzir quando clica no item em si, creio que no caso tem algo relacionado ao "itemView" q ta faltando mudar em algum lugar, _mas sua ajuda foi uma mao na roda vlw msm_
`viewHolder.ivPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()`
ivPlay seria o botao nos itens quando coloco itemView nao funciona.

Comment: entao, a duvida é essa de onde mais eu mudo o itemView, para reproduzir no item e não no botao de play(ivPlay)

Comment: Você pode até fazer um teste excluindo os botões ivPlay e ivStop já que eles não vão ter mais ação. Ao clicar em viewHolder.itemView que seria no item, já é pra reproduzir.

Comment: e como é o codigo pra parar uma audio quando eu começo a executar o outro?
-obrigado

Comment: tentei usar o onDestroy, para parar o audio anterior, mas n deu certo, como faço para parar, estou usando listview